# Не открывается окно Turtle

Tags: python-3.x

Уважаемые господа, здравствуйте!
Учусь по книге Златопольского "Основы программирования на Python". 
Использую MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
Анаконда 1.8.7. Как узнать версию своего питона, я не знаю, но скачивала я третий.

Нарисовала в Turtle шестиугольник. Открывается окошко Turtle, рисуется шестиугольник.
А потом я не могу снова открыть это окно, никакой новый код, который я пишу в ноутбуке, не работает. Снова открыть окно Turtle не получается. Что я делаю не так? 
На всякий случай, код выглядит вот так.

```
import turtle
turtle.reset()
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Прибавте строку

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

или

```
turtle.done()
```

на конец вашего `.py` файла (или кода в ячейке Jupyter Notebook):

```
import turtle
turtle.reset()
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.right(60)
turtle.done()              # Здесь
```

Затем нужно окно с шестиугольником вручную закрыть.

---

Версию вашего Питона узнаете так:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```